# MS Excel COUNTIF <= HOURS (HH:MM:SS) format

Tags: excel

I have a column "cycle time" with hh:mm:ss value format. I want to count the number of cells on the column which has the value of lesser than or equal to "04:00:00".

My below formula returns "0" value instead of "4". Here's the column values

[image]

and my formula is =COUNTIF('sheet1'!I:I,"<= 4:00:00")

Can anyone share me how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Basic unit in date and time is one day is 1. So a fraction of a day represents time.
One day is 24 hours, so 4hs is 1/24 * 4=0.16666667

`=COUNTIF('sheet1'!I:I,"<=0.16666667")`

I recommend you save this value in a cell, i.e. P1=4/24

`=COUNTIF('sheet1'!I:I,"<="&P1)`

And also, as @Jeped commented, using [TIME funciton](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TIME-function-9A5AFF99-8F7D-4611-845E-747D0B8D5457):

`=COUNTIF('sheet1'!I:I,"<="&TIME(4, 0, 0))`

Comment: this returns all the number of cells "14"

Comment: A more functional approach may using the [TIME function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TIME-function-9A5AFF99-8F7D-4611-845E-747D0B8D5457). e.g. `=COUNTIF('sheet1'!I:I,"<="&TIME(4, 0, 0))`